# Плеер - реализация кнопок play/pause

Tags: button, android

здравствуйте!!! 
пишу простенький интернет радио на андроиде... все работает всё играет. И вотрешил сделать одну кнопку
за место двух отвечающий за **play** и **pause**.. но ни как не могу понять что к чему... **помогите\подскажите плз**..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то у себя такое реализовывал:

```
boolean isPlaying = false;
void connect() {
    //подключаемся к потоку, начинаем воспроизведение
    mButton.setBackground(R.drawable.pause);
    isPlaying = true;
}

public void onClick(View v) { //OnClickListener
    if (isPlaying) {
        mPlayer.pause();
        mButton.setBackground(R.drawable.play); //меняем иконку на кнопке
        isPlaying = false;
}
else connect();
}
```

Comment: спасибо..ща будем пробовать..